# AWS ELB 4XXs count is the same as total request count, but all that requests still reach EC2 machines

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I've got a live IIS website with the following set up. CloudFront -> ELB -> TargetGroup -> EC2 Windows machines. There was an outage recently and I'm trying to understand why.

In the ELB monitors, I can see the spike of ELB 4XXs errors count and it's almost the same as Requests count (8k vs 7,9k). From what I understand, ELB 4XXs errors are LoadBalancer responses, so it should not reach the machines defined in the TargetGroup, but on the machine in IIS logs I can see the exact number of Request count from ELB monitor.

At the time it happened I had disabled acccess logs on the ELB (have enabled it recently). I'm not able to reproduce the spike because it's a live site and I'm still investigating what's happened.

Any idea why those ELB 4XXs requests reached my EC2 machines?

Comment: It would help to know which specific error codes were returned from the load balancer, but if you look at all the 4xx error codes a load balancer can return: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#load-balancer-http-error-codes I believe the 408 Timeout code can returned after the request has been sent to the server, if the server takes too long to respond.